# Distance from a point to a curve

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, hausdorff-distance

Given a continuous map $g:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$, Somebody know an efficient algorithm to compute the (say, the Euclidean) distance from a point $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $g(I)$?

Of course, it is an optimization problem of the form

$$ \min\{d(P,g(t)):t \in [0,1] \},$$

and as I need to solve the above problem for a set (large) of points $P$, such algorithm has to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks you in advance for your comments.

Comment: Is anything known about $g$ other than it is continuous? Is it piecewise smooth by any chance?

Comment: "A priori", only the continuity on $g$ is assumed. However, noticing that the polynomials are dense in the space of continuous functions, Do you know some algorithm for polynomials?  Thanks.